# ubuntu dual boot plus virtualbox

Tags: 16.04

Upgraded from win8.1 to win10. Then I installed oracle virtualbox and installed ubuntu 16.04 in that environment on a logical partition.

I set up a dual boot on my wife's machine (same upgrade) and that's working OK for her limited usage. (The only wrinkle is that nothing I've read in 2 weeks of research gets us the grub menu, and she still has to press Esc after power, then F9, then choose ubuntu.)

For me, the ability to have both win and ubuntu up and available at the same time is very nice.  That's because some ubuntu functions don't work in the vbox environment (screen capture images are only black--works OK on my wife's; LO base report builder works under win10 but not under ubuntu in vbox). When that happens, I can use win10 on the fly and get right back to my work in ubuntu without rebooting. That's really good.

I'm getting to the point where I might be comfortable using ubuntu by default (if I can get a grub menu) and only switch to win10 once in a while for special tasks. Questions:

If I install ubuntu on the SSD to set up a dual boot system -- and don't change the vbox/ubuntu setup:

1. will it overwrite what's been installed under vbox?
2. will I be able to continue to use win10/vbox/ubuntu as I do now?
3. will the changes I make to one ubuntu install (shared folders, launch bar) carry over to the other? I've done a lot of configuring/tweaking to the current ubuntu -- will they be wiped out. (I'll do them again, it's just extra time.) If I can run ubuntu as normal, standalone OS, will changes I make to it show up in the one that runs under vbox?

I haven't seen any discussion of this in the dual boot threads I've read.

Answer (score 2):

Your virtualbox installation under Windows 10 is completely independent of a dual boot Ubuntu installation. You will not overwrite anything of the Windows 10 partition, except when you overwrite it all by deleting the Windows partition. So if you're not certain what you're doing, don't do that unless you have a good backup!

Now because you already have a dual boot setup for your wife, you seem to know what you do.

When you start up Windows 10, everything should be as it was. Of course you should resize the partition, make the Windows partition smaller to reserve space for the Ubuntu partitions. Then the Ubuntu installation will recognize the Windows partition and offer to use the other space, set up a dual boot installation. That should be pretty easy, but again - if you're not sure and you may mess up important work - make sure you will not delete important files. Better stay with that VM for a while until you're sure! (Sorry for all those "sures"! ;-) )

Comment: thanks for the fast and succinct answer.  No worries at all about "be sure".

Comment: I manually resized partitions last year when I tried this w/o vbox.  Can I do that after installing the second instance of ubuntu?

Comment: You should resize the Windows partition in Windows. See http://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/ What do you mean with second instance? The Virtualbox VM is just a file on a disk, like a Word document. It has nothing to do with your dual boot Ubuntu. If you're afraid to destroy it, export the VM in Virtualbox and write it to an external disk. You can import it later.

Comment: then again, I shared my main documents/pics/etc folders from win, and I use the very same data files.  So I'm only using the ubuntu partition for that system, not for a lot of new files.

Comment: OK I see. In Virtualbox you can share folders on your Windows partition. Do you share folders from the Ubuntu VM? That's not wise, better keep it on the windows partition, unless you need file permissions that don't work on Windows. You either use the VM or the Dual boot Ubuntu, both can use those shared files, although via a different method.

Comment: second instance -- the install under vbox created the files needed for ubuntu.  If I install ubuntu the normal dual boot way -- I'm wondering whether that will create a second set of ubuntu system files on a separate logical partition that will be accessed in the normal dual boot procedure.  Would be nice if there were just one set to configure, but workable if not

Comment: I don't share from ubuntu to win file system.  I gather that if I do the additional install, I'll be able to hit the same files from win, standalone ubuntu, and ubuntu-under-vbox

Comment: No, this is not an option. You have two systems. They are separate, have their own system files. The VM might be able to access the Ubuntu disks if you know how to configure that, but not for system files. You should realize that they are different systems. The VM has a layer inbetween, Virtualbox, which delivers all drivers that communicate with the host. The Ubuntu VM thinks that Virtualbox is the hardware, and uses drivers for that hardware - Virtualbox virtual hardware. The dualboot Ubuntu uses the real hardware. Settings will be different. Don't mess this up.

Comment: I think we're on the same page.  When I said "hit the same files" I was talking about the data files (*.ods, *.odt, etc.) by sharing the directories.  Willing to live with configuring 2 instances of ubuntu. If it works, I wouldn't be using win or win/vbox/ubuntu often

Comment: You can turn this around. My setup at work: Ubuntu 16.04 plus Virtualbox for XP. The network settings are local only because XP is no longer secure, so no connection to the internet, and I use it for programs that don't work on Linux. I don't need W7 or W10 for this, for now. You should keep your data files in one place. An alternative is to keep them in dropbox (or similar), and then they can be local everywhere, unless they're too big.